# How to decide which is the most secure way to generate random numbers in java using SecureRandom class

Tags: java, secure-random

I am wondering which is the best way to generate highly secured random number in range 0-255 and moreover with fast speed performance. It comes to me that for sure i have to use SecureRandom class but i am not sure if i have to use .getInstance(SHA1PRNG) or is better to let it default with no arg constructor.

I am between these two choices :

First way

```
 public class RandomGenerator {

  private static final String sha1prng = "SHA1PRNG";

    private final SecureRandom csprng;
    private final byte[] bytes = new byte[1];

    public RandomGenerator() { 
        try { 
            csprng = SecureRandom.getInstance(sha1prng); 
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        csprng.nextBoolean(); 
    }



    protected int generateByte() {
        do {
            csprng.nextBytes(bytes);
        } while (bytes[0] == 0); 

        return ((byte)(bytes[0] & 0xff) + 256) % 256;
     }

  }
```

Secondway :

```
 public class SomethingThatNeedsRandomBytes {

  private static final int NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_BYTES = ... ;

  private final SecureRandom csprng;

 SomethingThatNeedsRandomBytes(SecureRandom csprng) {
   if (csprng == null)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();

     this.csprng = csprng;

    }

   void doSomethingInvolvingRandomness() {
     byte[] bytes = new byte[NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_BYTES];
     csprng.nextBytes(bytes);
// Do something with random bytes here.
     }
  }
```

I have seen a lot of other answers in this sites and most of them suggest not to use SHA1PRNG and let it default but on the other hand some other answers suggest to use NativePRNG (which i do not prefer since it is not fast) or SHA1PRNG. I would like to have a feedback of which of the ways generate high secure random numbers and which is the fastest one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really asking how to decide, or just what the answer is?

Comment: @EJP I want to know how to decide that? Ok i can do speed performance test using benchmarking or System.nanoTime () but i do not know how to decide which is more secured

Answer (score 0):

With an empty constructor, SecureRandom will select the first registered security Provider that supports a SecureRandom algorithm; if none exists, this will default to SHA1PRNG. This will vary depending on the system, if your application may be run in different environments, you should specify the algorithm in the constructor. To retrieve the order of security Providers for SecureRandom, you can run the following:

```
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Provider.Service;

for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
    for (Service service : provider.getServices()) {
        if (service.getType().equals("SecureRandom")) {
            System.out.println(service.getAlgorithm());
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of NativePRNG depends on the operating system, but typically uses entropy generated by hardware or operating system events to produce random values. Often this must wait for entropy to be generated before a value can be returned. In absolute terms, this is more secure than SHA1PRNG; however, practically you are unlikely to notice the difference. If the speed of the algorithm is important for the application, SHA1PRNG will generally be faster than NativePRNG, and both algorithms provide sufficiently random values for cryptographic operations. It should be noted that for applications such as password hashing, a slower algorithm is typically preferred.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#SecureRandom--

Comment: D.Holland I really appreciate it . It was really helpful for me. I am using ShamirSecretSharing scheme in which it have to be applied for each byte of the file and if the file is let say some Gb then using NativePRNG it will take me a lot of time to share and reconstruct the file. My operations are based on GF(256) which is the most efficient one and i have used Horner's rule to evaluate the polynomial which reduce the number of multiplications. So what do you think is secure enough if i use SHA1PRNG ? The reason i am asking is because i do not find an way to proof which is more secured